# Changing y axis max in time series R

Tags: r, time-series, data-science

The ts() object in R doesn't seem to let you use ylim so I'm unable to set a customized y axis range for my time series. If i do use ylim i get a unused variable error. This is what i have for plotting my time series:

```
dataTimeSeries <- ts(newru$Value, start = c(input$years[1]), end = input$years[2])
plot.ts(dataTimeSeries)
abline(h=amount$toxicityLevels, col="blue")   #add horizontal line
```

I'm trying to add a horizontal line to the time series graph via the abline function, but sometimes the y axis isn't large enough for the line to actually show which is why I'm wondering if theres another way to extend the y axis. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to hack the function. Unfortunately, you have committed a neubie error on SO: failure to post a reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If your question has been answered, please mark it is the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axis limits are being set in the `plot.ts()` call. If you want to override the data, set it there, or before there with `par()`.

plotting behavior can be a little unexpected, though, so I can't guarantee it will work without a dput of your data, but here are two options for you to try:

```
dataTimeSeries <- ts(newru$Value, start = c(input$years[1]), end = input$years[2])
plot.ts(dataTimeSeries, ylim = c(<your min>, <your max>))
abline(h=amount$toxicityLevels, col="blue")
```

Alternatively

```
dataTimeSeries <- ts(newru$Value, start = c(input$years[1]), end = input$years[2])
par(ylim = c(<your min>, <your max>)
plot.ts(dataTimeSeries)
abline(h=amount$toxicityLevels, col="blue")
```